# Initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] - whats wrong?

Tags: c

I have this warning in my code:

> initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

code is as follows:

```
/*
* Method return some number :-)
* It is TEST METHOD
*/
int check(char array[]) {

        int num = 0; // my number

        char **elem_p = array; // test

        while (*elem_p) { // it is while

            num++;
            elem_p++;

        }
        return num; // my return
    }
```

What is wrong? How can I fix this?
Thank you. Test method is not relevant, is a sample.

Comment: Why is `elem_p` a `char **`? It's not a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 11):

> What is wrong?

`array` is of type `char *` (pointer to `char`) but you are using it to initialize `char **` (pointer to pointer to `char`) type variable `elem_p`.

> How can I fix this?

Make pointer and pointee (object to be pointed) compatible to each other. Declare `elem_p` as `char *`;

```
char *elem_p = array;
```

Answer (score 1):

`char array[]` will be rewritten as `char* array`. You either need `char* array[]` or `char** array`, but there is no difference in a function declaration. You probably intended to only have one asterisk, as haccks points out.

```
char* array[]) {

        int num = 0; // my number

        char **elem_p = array; // test
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `char *elem_p = array;`. For more information, see 'Pointers and Arrays' at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/.